# vector/list of abstract base class objects in SWIG C++/Python

Tags: python, c++, swig

*Note:* The corresponding Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/nschloe/c6d1dcb0837031183da0da5423ea23f6).

---

In a SWIGged C++/Python application, I'd like to create a function that accepts a `std::vector`/Python list of abstract base class objects, e.g.,

```
#ifndef MYTEST_HPP
#define MYTEST_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class MyBaseClass {
  public:
  virtual void eval() const = 0;
};

class MyTestClass: public MyBaseClass {
  public:
  virtual void eval() const {
    std::cout << "MyTestClass::eval()" << std::endl;
  }
};

void
mytest(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyBaseClass>> & a) {
  std::cout << "length: " << a.size() << std::endl;
}

#endif // MYTEST_HPP
```

Note that we're using `std::shared_ptr`s here. Using this with

```
%module mytest

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "mytest.hpp"
%}

%include <std_shared_ptr.i>
%shared_ptr(MyBaseClass);
%shared_ptr(MyTestClass);

%include <std_vector.i>
namespace std {
%template(List) vector<std::shared_ptr<MyBaseClass>>;
}

%include "mytest.hpp"
```

does compile, but fails at runtime. From

```
import mytest
a = mytest.MyTestClass()
mytest.mytest([a])
```

one gets

```
python: /tmp/l/build/mytestPYTHON_wrap.cxx:2385: int SWIG_Python_ConvertPtrAndOwn(PyObject*, void**, swig_type_info*, int, int*): Assertion `own' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any hints?

Comment: Why would you expect a python list to be converted to a `std::vector`. Use `l = mytest.List()` then `l.append(a)` and finally `mytest.mytest(l)`. It will print `length: 1` as anticipated

Comment: Sorry. What you have made actually works fine for me. I use SWIG 3.0.2 and Python 2.7. What happens if you do it using the `append` approach?

Comment: Thanks @JensMunk for your comments! The `append` trick actually works. The crash happens with SWIG 3.0.8; perhaps a regression? I'll file a bug.

Comment: You should. It works in 3.0.2. I anticipate that they have introduced a bug

Comment: https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/773

Comment: @JensMunk The reason why it works for you is probably because your SWIG is compiled with `-DNDEBUG` which skips the checks.

Comment: It works in both debug and release. I use g++ 4.9.2-10